# Using babel-register with AVA and .babelrc's `"ignore": false`, but node_modules are not being transpiled

Tags: babeljs, ava

I'm trying to have source files (and their dependencies in node_modules) be transpiled when running AVA tests. I've configured AVA to require `babel-register` and inherit my `.babelrc` file with the following in `package.json`:

```
"ava": {
    "require": "babel-register",
    "babel": "inherit"
  }
```

and this in `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": [ "es2015" ],
  "ignore": false
}
```

I have [a test spec that imports a source file](https://github.com/tomwayson/esri-rollup-example/blob/b9aff3171db91cbe332ebdf0bc7183e793ff5609/test/unit/utilSpec.js#L2) with and [that source file imports an ES2015 dependency from node_modules](https://github.com/tomwayson/esri-rollup-example/blob/b9aff3171db91cbe332ebdf0bc7183e793ff5609/test/unit/utilSpec.js#L2):

However, when running `ava` I see:

```
/Users/me/code/esri-rollup-example/node_modules/capitalize-word/index.js:2
export default input => input.replace(regexp, match => match.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + match.substr(1));
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

Which tells me that the source file (`src/app/utils.js`) did transpile, but it's dependency in node_modules (`capitalize-string/index`) did not.

Both the source modules and dependencies transpile fine when I use babel CLI, so it really seems like the `.babelrc`'s `"ignore": false` setting is not getting passed to `babel-register`. I can see from the babel docs that you can [explicitly pass an ignore option to `babel-register`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/), but I don't see how you can do that from the AVA config. I even tried adding the following to my test file before the line where it imports the source files, but I still see the same error:

```
require("babel-register")({
  ignore: false
});
```

I suppose I could add a transpile step before testing, but I wanted to make sure that I wasn't just missing some AVA or babel configuration first.

Comment: Did you find any answers? I have a similar issue.

Comment: No. Not yet. In this case, I just chose not to use AVA for now.

Answer (score 4):

This is related to issue in babel itself – https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T6726

But you can put `babel-register` require in separate file (let call it `.setup.js`):

```
require('babel-register')({
    ignore: /node_modules\/(?!capitalize\-word)/i
});

const noop = function () {};

require.extensions['.css'] = noop; // If you want to ignore some CSS imports
```

And then change `"require": "babel-register"` to `"require": "./.setup.js"`

Comment: thanks @floatdrop. I checked out my old branch tried this, and I _think_ it fixed this issue, as I no longer see the above error. However, I get other errors now. I moved on from using AVA on this project and that branch is so out of date now, that I just don't have the time to get it working right now.
If others can verify that this works for them, I'll mark it correct.